# warning while setting table row height for a tableView cell -iOS 9

Tags: ios, uitableview

i am trying to use a custom cell for my table view.
but i try to use this code:

```
self.table.estimatedRowHeight = 500.0; 
    self.table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

its giving me a warning: Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.
please tell me what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` then you must use autolayout and give proper constraints.

Because `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` depends on autolayout. so make sure you gave proper constraint to your tableview's cell content.

first element of cell should have top constrains and last should have bottom and every element should have connection vertically via top or bottom constraint.

Refer [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html) for more detail.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this... same scenario i found in my tableview i set proper constraint but every time get this warning **"Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead"** but i have just remove the **heightForRowAtIndexPath** i was having something like that

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

just comment if you have `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. i get the result. it works proper for me.

Answer (score -1):

maybe your constraints cannot figure out the row height itself. You can obviously set row height with fix value.

```
self.table.rowHeight = 500
```

Comment: This is not right way of using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. It's main concern is to calculate height as per content size of cell. If you are giving fix row height then it will not increase more than 500 if content size will be large than also.

Comment: @Lion That`s right. If the author want dynamic row height. Make rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension and layout cell content with enough constraints so it can figure out the row height. If the author want fix row height. Just set it.